# backbone.js - Undefined is not a function

Tags: backbone.js

I've started learning Backbone.js and tried to write my first app with Collections. Here is the code:

```
console.clear();
(function($){

   window.App = {

      Models : {},
      Collections : {},
      Views : {}

   };



   //a single estimate
   App.Models.Estimate = Backbone.Model.extend({});

   // multiple esitmates
   App.Collections.Estimates  = Backbone.Collection.extend({


      model : App.Collections.Estimate


   });


   App.Views.Estimates = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'ul',


      render : function(){

      this.collection.each(this.addTo,this);

   },
      addTo:function(estimate){

         var dir = App.Views.Estimate({model:estimate}).render();
         this.$el.append(dir.el);

      }





   });


   App.Views.Estimate  = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'li',


      render :function(){

         this.$el.html(this.model.get('title'));
         return this;
      }


   });



   var jSon = [{title:'Abhiram', estimate:8}];
   var estimates = new App.Collections.Estimates(jSon);
    console.log(estimates);

   var tasksView = new App.Views.Estimates({collection:estimates});
  // var a = tasksView.render().el;
   //console.log(a);

})($j||jQuery);
```

I've all the three included :

jQuery first, Underscore next and Backbone. I keep getting "Undefined is not a function".Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you find out what line generates the error?

Comment: `App.Models.Estimate = Backbone.Model.extend({});` is equal to `App.Models.Estimate = Backbone.Model;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to assign collection `App.Collections.Estimate` as model to it self?

```
// multiple esitmates
App.Collections.Estimates  = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : App.Collections.Estimate
});
```

Comment: What did you change it to?